# Issue with Kotlin version while building Flutter APK

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, gradle, apk

I recently updated my Android Studio and moved my project from Windows to Mac, when I run application on Android device. It works fine but when i run command

```
flutter build apk --split-per-abi
```

It gives me errors.

**Things which tried and didn't work**

**Tried #1**

After applying flutter fix:

I changed my project ext.kotlin version from Android/build.gradle to latest (1.9.0)

But it gave me error my Kotlin IDE version in not same as my project, i.e (1.8.0)
I reverted back to (1.8.0)

Currently ext.kotlin in adnroid/build.bradle is 1.8.0
Android Studio IDE kotlin plugin version is 1.8.0

**TRIED #2**

- Deleted caches from users/syedAsif/.gradle
- invalidated caches
- removed .gradle from android folder
- Rebuilt app (Not worked and same kotlin error)

**TRIED #3**

- Deleted .gradle from users/syedAsif/
- invalidated caches
- removed .gradle from android folder
- Rebuilt app (Not worked and same kotlin error)

Error while building apk
[image]

Errors while building apk

[image]

Flutter Doctor

[image]

**Packages I'm using:**

```
firebase_core: ^2.1.1
cloud_firestore: ^4.0.3
firebase_auth: ^4.0.0
firebase_storage: ^11.0.9
get: ^4.6.5
get_storage: ^2.0.3
cached_network_image: ^3.2.2
intl: ^0.18.0
image_picker: ^1.0.1
flutter_bloc: ^8.1.1
smooth_page_indicator: ^1.0.0+2
syncfusion_flutter_gauges: ^22.1.39
flutter_svg: ^2.0.7
table_calendar: ^3.0.8
google_sign_in: ^6.1.4
flutter_facebook_auth: ^5.0.7
sign_in_with_apple: ^5.0.0
the_apple_sign_in: ^1.1.1
permission_handler: ^10.2.0
shimmer: ^3.0.0
firebase_crashlytics: ^3.0.15
# wakelock: ^0.6.2
google_mobile_ads: ^3.0.0
firebase_messaging: ^14.4.0
flutter_slidable: ^3.0.0
in_app_purchase: ^3.1.5
flutter_widget_from_html: ^0.10.3
provider: ^6.0.5
assets_audio_player: ^3.0.6
gdpr_dialog: ^2.1.1
flutter_native_timezone: ^2.0.0
flutter_local_notifications: ^14.1.1
# health: ^7.0.1
url_launcher: ^6.1.11
google_fonts: ^4.0.4
connectivity_plus: ^4.0.1
lottie: ^2.5.0
internet_connection_checker: ^1.0.0+1
skeletons: ^0.0.3
```

**Android/build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.4'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Gradle properties:**

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608m
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Comment: Please do not post text error messages as screen shot. That makes it har to read and bad for searching text in it.

Comment: Initially I added Error log as text and I was not able to upload that because stackoverflow was marking my question "SPAM".

Comment: facing same issue from days and haven't found any solution yet

Answer (score 0):

In your gradle, downgrade to version 1.5.1 as the build error reports.

**The build expect the version 1.5.1 but you are providing the version 1.8.0.**

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.1' <--- This One
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.3'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.4'
}
```

}

If this doesn't solve your problem please let me know providing updated informations / errors so I can help you! Happy coding

Comment: Other packages are using higher kotlin_version. this change will effect other packages.

Answer (score 0):

The Main Problem was in SignConfig release. You can see that in the screen shot .It's after
"What went wrong" line.

Cause: I moved my project from windows to mac via github repo and as I added in gitignore file to not move the "upload-keystore" so release config was missing that . Although KOTLIN VERSION problem stays the same.

Comment: are you able to build apk now ?

Comment: @RameshSanghar Yes